# Character Count - Truncate the Characters when Pasted

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, counter

If the user enters more characters than are allowed into a `textarea`, how can I truncate them?

[This](http://cssglobe.com/post/7161/jquery-plugin-simplest-twitterlike-dynamic-character-count-for-textareas) is the plugin am using for character count, and [here](http://cssglobe.com/lab/charcount/01.html) is the demo page.

**The relevant code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    //default usage
    $("#message1").charCount();

    //custom usage
    $("#message2").charCount({
      allowed: 50,      
      warning: 20,
      counterText: 'Characters left: '  
    });
  });
</script>


<label for="message">Type your message</label>
<textarea id="message1" name="message1"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#message1").change(function(){
    var length = 50;
    var text = $(this).text()
    if(text.length > length){
        var myTruncatedString = text.substring(0,length);
        $(this).text(myTruncatedString);
    }
});
```